# CreateObject("Excel.Application") без установленного Microsoft Office

Tags: excel, vbscript

Есть рабочий VBScript код, который генерирует несколько excel файлов. Переезжаем на новый сервер, где Microsoft Office не установлен.
Естественно `CreateObject("Excel.Application")` не работает.

Как решить проблему без установки Excel? Поделитесь проверенными способами.

Comment: А никак. Всё зависит от поставленной задачи. Если задача не сложная - то с xslx можно работать как с xml например. Если сложная - искать альтернативные библиотеки.

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант можно сохранять результат в Google Sheets при помощи opensource [GSpread.NET](http://scand.com/products/gspread/index.html). 
Библиотека позволяет работать с Google Sheets используя Microsoft Excel API.
Весь код не переписывать не надо.

Замени **CreateObject("Excel.Application")** на **CreateObject("GSpreadCOM.Application")**.

И работай с Google Sheets как с обычным Microsoft Excel документом.